# Two parallel relays for double current

Tags: relay

Can I use two relays to increase current rating? I have requirement of 12 A, 240 VAC load, but I have 7 A, 250 VAC relays. Can I add two relays to make 7 A + 7 A, relay which is driven by single input signal?

TLDR; Can we add relay to increase current for inductive load / (mono-motor of 1hp = 0.75kW)?[image]

Comment: What's the load?

Comment: It depends on the relay and how you are going to use them. Some relays are specified to pass more current than they are able to make or break, so whatever your relay data sheet says about it should be taken into account. We don't know what relay you are going to use but in general, if you don't know, that's a no and you can't parallel them.

Comment: You may use a single relay to control a contactor designed for switching about 20 A or more. So switching the compressor motor start current peak would not be a problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any constraint that does not allow you to use a single, bigger relay, or a solid state relays (pricier though)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The relays will not operate at exactly the same speed so one set of contacts will take the brunt of the switching, and when closed they may not share current equally. In both cases, beyond specifications so they may weld or die very prematurely.

Sometimes contacts on the *same* device are allowed to be paralleled for increased current, and that will be specified in the datasheet.

TL;DR: No

Comment: Particularly bad for motor loads, which can be very badly behaved at startup / shutdown, just those instants where you have only one relay engaged.

Comment: @Dannie yes, motor load, *compressor* motor load, tungsten load, "TV" electronic load, inductive load etc. are all much worse than resistive loads.

Comment: I'll add that they might have very different contact resistances, like 10mΩ and 20mΩ, which means they won't necessarily share current equally even after the contacts are fully closed.

Answer (score 12):

There are 3 states in relay switching a motor.

1. Making contact. Inductance starts at 0 current. No stress, just start caps.
2. During surge currents 5 to 8x rated current.  Derate relay from resistive max current to 30% of rated current depending on datasheet. Add a snubber to extinguish some arc energy that raises contact surface to > 5000 'K (white light)
3. Break contacts. V=LdI/dt  big arc energy stored in motor. E=1/2L^2 is converted to arc energy

N**ot only can you not double** **up on contacts** during switching but you need 3.3x (min) rated motor current in most power relays 2.2x rated in others depending on motor duty factor and relay.  (absolute MAX)

Ionization time is required for opening contacts to detonate air into a burning hot gas. 1~3 few us The faster the relay contacts move the long it takes as the breakdown voltage 2kV/mm increases. Then the voltage collapses and the arc can then stretch until the motor current drops below holding current for the contact gap and current rating. DC requires a bigger gap.
Once air ionizes like lightning but in a short path, it conducts in 10's on nanoseconds or less.

The stress on a relay contacts depends on the electrical time constant as well as current and spring force (loud click) Every coil has a V/I spec or a coil DCR resistance. Some also give inductance but they tend to be in the Henry range.

Thus Tau=L/R can be large and the spring force a=F/m.  You can increase R greatly on opening by adding a diode and Zener well below transistor Vceo or simply use V=IR and use that R in series with the diode and add a small EMI RF cap across R for RC=10 us. Thus you can improve Relay reliability in the contacts by speeding up the coil but beware of EMI both from the contact arc which spans > xx MHz and coil f-3dB =~ 0.2/Tau or f-3dB = 0.35 / 10~90%T

### Reason

Synchronizing these events is highly uncertain even with identical relays as the voltage collapses on the 1 relay to open 1st thus reducing stress on the 2nd.

Read a good OMRON RELAY spec under DURABILITY. Learn every detail.

https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g6b.pdf

Answer (score 7):

No.

The first contact to make and the last to break has to switch all the current.

Answer (score 1):

Not with 240VAC, no.  Paralleling isn't allowed in AC mains power unless the amps and wire size are quite large and certain protection is provided.

Further, to manipulate AC power you need equipment which is listed for the task.  The equipment will have a variety of ratings, and you need to conform with the rating that fits your equipment.  For instance motors have a different rating than resistive loads, due to the need to interrupt inductive kick.

Just buy the right thing, don't improvise.